# NServiceBus Message Queues Builds Up

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

We are struggling to get a good performance from NServiceBus 4.0.4 with MSMQ. We experience that when the messages comes in at a slow rate at about 40-50 messages a second every thing works well and our handler are able to keep the queue empty.

Increasing the message rate to like 400 messages a second average the handler cannot keep up any more. Our handlers are just an empty handler without any logic at this point. They seem to maybe cover about 300 messages out of 400 average per second, and the message queue slowly builds.

And here is where I really struggle to understand what happens. If I then increase further to like 1500 -2000 message a second the handlers step up the game and handles close to 1500 messages a second, the queue still build but not with the extra amount of messages.

We have tried to fiddle with `NumberOfWorkerThreads`(On/Off and 0- 100), `MaxRetries`(On/Off and 0- 100), `MaximumConcurrencyLevel`(On/Off and 0- 100), `MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond`(On/Off and 0 - 10000) and `IsTransitional`(On/Off) Nothing seems to influence this behavior.

We are able to send thousands of messages, but not handle them, even though handling of today is picking them from the queue and throwing them away.

Does anyone know what this may come from, or have any good tips to how we can increase the performance of our bus?

Comment: I assume you have an unlimited license?

Comment: When you checkout the repo there should be perd tests. Could you run those and report back?

Comment: @DanielMarbach means "perf" tests.

Comment: I am running a NService developer lisense so i think that should be ulimited. Daniel: i will check back with perf test

Answer (score 0):

When testing this issue  i tested runneing the process without debugger from VS studio. It turns out that for some reason my installation of VS2013 attached debugger anyway.

When i detached debbugger i still had some connection to the NServiceBus.host process. Running the appilication outside VS speeded up everything substansially, and therby solved this issue for me. I then reinstalled VS, and the issues whent away there as well.

sorry for any inconvenience.